# How to model a shape using Smart Boolean operation

Tags: modeling, modifiers, topology

I'm trying to make a shape in the cube mesh using smart Boolean method. It gets the job done, but leaves ngons and messy topology. Is there another way to make those circular objects into the mesh of the cube with another method to have better topology instead of using the Boolean operation?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subdivide a plane, keep its borders only:

[image]

Extrude inwards, then right click > *LoopTools > Circle*, then extrude again and at the end fill the center:

[image]

Use the *Select > Checker Deselect* to select one edge out of 2, enable *Transform Pivot Point > Individual Origins*:

[image]

Scale down the selected edges to align their length with the inner circle:

[image]

Extrude the whole mesh downward, then select the rectangles with the *Checker Deselect*:

[image]

Extrude these rectangles:

[image]

Comment: exceptional, thank you!